# list of Json to dataframe in python

Tags: python, json, pandas, list

I want to convert a list of JSON strings into a proper DataFrame.

input:

```
x=['{"a":{"df":"9.0"},"b":{"df":"1234"}}',
   '{"a":{"fg":"3.0"},"b":{"fg":"1234"}}']
```

expected output:

```
a       t        b
9.0     df      1234 
3.0     fg      1234
```

I tried the following codes but it did not work.

```
pd.DataFrame.from_records(x)
pd.DataFrame.from_dict(x)
```

Maybe its requires iteration, I am not sure about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to use [`pandas.read_json`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_json.html) and [`pandas.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html):

```
pd.concat(map(pd.read_json, x)).rename_axis('t').reset_index()
```

output:

```
    t  a     b
0  df  9  1234
1  fg  3  1234
```